# Carthage: Updating a legacy app (Advice)

Tags: swift, carthage

I have this app that I'm supposed to update to be releasable to the app store. However, it hasn't been touched since Swift 2. Currently the Cartfile looks like this...

```
github "mxcl/OMGHTTPURLRQ" "3.1.1"
github "mxcl/PromiseKit" "3.5.1"
github "pusher/pusher-websocket-swift" "swift-2.3"
github "getsentry/sentry-cocoa" "3.2.0"
```

I need advice on the best approach to take to update this app.

Things I need to know in specific:

- Can I release to the app store with the code being in Swift 3
- The versions of the dependencies to work with Swift 3/4
- Best course of action to update the app.

I know this is an incredibly specific question, but I'd be so grateful for anything that could help.

Comment: If you are already in the process on updating the Swift version of the code, I'd recommend going all the way updating to the latest version, Swift 4. Simply update all packages to the latest stable version and update the source code of the legacy code to the current Swift version (4.1) as well. The problem with your question isn't being too specific, on the contrary, it's too broad IMHO and also borderline opinion based.

Comment: Apple is going to require apps (to be on the App Store) be built with Xcode 9 starting in July so that pretty much requires using Swift 4.